# What is the difference between these two queries pls?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When updating a table from another or performing query that involves comparing two tables, I normally have a habit of querying like below

```
UPDATE dbo.Table1 SET COL =
(
 SELECT i.colid FROM 
    dbo.Table2 i 
      WHERE i.did = dbo.Table1.did and 
         i.[pdate] = dbo.Table1.pdate and
         i.pamount = dbo.Table1.pay and 
         i.[Ref No ] = dbo.Table1.refno and
         i.[cNo ] = dbo.Table1.receipt
)
```

AND recently the above failed me. It returns an error saying query returns morethan 1 record/row. However My superior queried like below and it works . I still cant figure out why mine failed and his succeed. And why it never failed me before ?

```
UPDATE dbo.Table1 SET COL = i.colid 
from
 dbo.Table2 i 
   WHERE i.did = dbo.Table1.did and 
         i.[pdate] = dbo.Table1.pdate and
         i.pamount = dbo.Table1.pay and 
         i.[Ref No ] = dbo.Table1.refno and
         i.[cNo ] = dbo.Table1.receipt
```

Comment: Your original query wouldn't fail if there weren't duplicate data in `Table2` for those `where` criteria.  However, once `Table2` matched on multiple rows, you receive your error.  You can make your original query work by using `SELECT TOP 1` in the subquery.  I think the `JOIN` though is preferable over the `correlated subquery`.

Comment: Thanks sir. What confuses me is that his also supposely returns a duplicate. So why his passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query fails because it returns more than one row.  That is, there are two or more rows that match the conditions.  I think this is pretty obvious from the error.  You have a scalar subquery.  It should return at most one row and one column.

The second works, because joins are allowed to have multiple rows matching.  However, only one of the values is set set -- from one of the arbitrary matching rows.  In my opinion, it is bad form to have multiple multiple matching rows match and have an arbitrary value chosen.  But, it does work.

Comment: When you said are allowed to have multiple rows matching, d you mean his returned more than one matching row also ?

Comment: Related: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms177523.aspx *The results of an UPDATE statement are undefined if the statement includes a FROM clause that is not specified in such a way that only one value is available for each column occurrence that is updated, that is if the UPDATE statement is not deterministic. For example, in the UPDATE statement in the following script, both rows in Table1 meet the qualifications of the FROM clause in the UPDATE statement; but it is undefined which row from Table1 is used to update the row in Table2.*

Comment: @NuruSalihu . . . The matching logic is the same in the two queries.  For the first, the context says only one row is allowed so the database returns an error.  For the second, multiple rows are allowed, but only one is arbitrarily chosen for the update.

Comment: oic. So what is your opinion. Is it prefarable if i continue with my way and add `top 1` as suggested by a sgeddes above or should adopt my superior's ? Mine never fails and was disappointed today because i confedently told him cannot and he succeded.

Comment: @NuruSalihu . . . I think you should decide which of the matching rows you want and choose accordingly.  You should use `top 1` with an `order by` clause or `row_number()`.  The point is to be intentional.  Don't let the database choose an arbitrary value, unless that is what you really, really mean.